# Escaped "escape" in key binding with :execute normal! is not getting escaped! String is terminated in middle of remap

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I am making some remaps for inserting/removing comments and "dividers" for different languages. In my ftplugins files the variable `g:CommentChar` is defined. For some reason I am getting the following error:

`E114: Missing quote: "\
E15: Invalid expression: ":normal! mA^i".g:CommentChar."\`

when trying to use the `<Leader>c` macro. How is this possible? I thought `<Esc>` was valid in execute command if it was escaped.

```
nnoremap <Leader>_ :execute 'normal! mAo'.g:CommentChar.'\<esc>100a-\<esc>`A'
nnoremap <Leader>c :execute 'normal! mA^i'.g:CommentChar.'\<esc>`A'
nnoremap <Leader>C :execute 'normal! mA^mBi'.g:CommentChar.'\<esc>f'.g:CommentChar.'dl`Bdl`A'
vnoremap <Leader>c :execute ':s/^/'.g:CommentChar.'/<CR>:noh<CR>'
vnoremap <Leader>C :execute ':s/'.g:CommentChar.'//<CR>:noh<CR>'
```

Comment: You can insert ^M by pressing Ctrl and v and then M. Use ^M as an alternative for `<CR>` This might help you if none of the ways worked out.

Comment: Replace double quotes `"` by single quotes `'`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Tried it. That's not the problem.

Comment: It's part of the problem.  There is no such thing as single backslash inside double quotes. _shrug_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<expr>` instead of `:execute 'normal! ...'`:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>_ 'mao'.g:CommentChar.'<Esc>100a-<Esc>`a<CR>'
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>c 'mA^i'.g:CommentChar.'<Esc>`A<CR>'
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>C 'mA^mBi'.g:CommentChar.'<Esc>f'.g:CommentChar.'dl`Bdl`A<CR>'
vnoremap <expr> <Leader>c ':s/^/'.g:CommentChar.'/<CR>:noh<CR>'
vnoremap <expr> <Leader>C ':s/'.g:CommentChar.'//<CR>:noh<CR>'
```

Comment: Thanks! So <expr> just means evaluate the RHS as string, then that's your macro.

Could you tell me why my first try didn't work? I was following the direction of [this "learn Vimscript the hard way" article](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/30.html).

Comment: @LukeDavis Pretty much, yes.  See `:h :map-<expr>`.

Comment: Any idea for the question ^^ in my edit?

Comment: @LukeDavis I'm not familiar with that part of the code.  I presume it has to do with `<Esc>` breaking out of `:exec`.  Ask on `vim_dev` for qualified opinions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :execute 'normal! mA^i'.g:CommentChar.'\<esc>`A'
```

is that `<esc>` is valid in `nnoremap`, never mind `execute`
and causes the command line up to that point to be executed.
(Plus you're missing a `<CR>` at the end of the mapping.)

One way around this is:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :execute 'normal! mA^i'.g:CommentChar.'^V^V^V^[`A'<CR>
```

where ^V is a literal Ctrl-V character and ^[ is a literal escape character.

The `^V^V^V^[` is translated to `^V^[` upon playback, which
inserts an escape character.

If you really want to use `execute`, do it like this.

```
:exe 'nnoremap <Leader>c mA^i' . g:CommentChar . '<Esc>`A'
```

At this point you may as well use `<expr>` as shown in @SatoKatsura's answer. The difference with `map <expr>` is that the expression is evaluated at runtime, and a few operations are disallowed (see `:h map-<expr>`).